# Expose fields of child on parent view

Tags: odoo

It seems like its impossible to expose a field via child-navigation (one2many child) onto a parent view (e.g. tree view).

Parent-View:

`<field name="child.child_field"/>`

Doesn't matter if type of `child_field` is simple or complex, the error is always:

> Error while validating view. The field `child.child_field` doesn't
>   exist.

**Is this possible in ODOO 13 or not?**

Best regards,
Lars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `related` field in parent model first. For e.g. `related_child_field = fields.Char(related='child.child_field')`. Then, use that field in view `<field name="related_child_field"/>`

I tried to do the same when I started with odoo. You cannot use dotted notion to child field in odoo list view, form view, etc. It is not just in odoo13, it also does not work in odoo11 which I usually use. So, I guess it will be the same for earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [views documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/views.html#semantic-components), the field renders (and allow edition of, possibly) a single field of the current record.

Comment: True, but a odoo.field can also represent a *2many cardinality, if you're talking about this. Then the widgets (e.g. widgets=many2many_tags) come into play, which are able to display a *2many relation in a single field.

Comment: Can you explain how using the `widget` attribute is related to your question (Using `<field name="child.child_field"/>` syntax)?